# redirect in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have a question regarding `.htaccess` redirects that after searching high and low, can't seem to find the answer to. My situation is this:

I have a website `www.website.com.au` which runs a Magento store. Magento itself is located in 
`www.website.com.au/magento`.

I use .htaccess to redirect

`www.website.com.au/magento`

to

`www.website.com.au`

As I am starting up a blog, I have now installed WordPress in `www.website.com.au/magento/blog`, and want to redirect this directory to `www.website.com.au/blog`.

(I don't want to integrate Magento and WordPress, but keep them as separate themes)

I have tried a few different options but what happens so far is:

I enter the URL of `www.website.com.au/blog`, which opens the WordPress blog page but the URL is displayed as

`www.website.com.au/magento/blog`.

However when clicking on one of the posts, the page then goes to the post and displays as

`www.website.com.au/blog/?p=1` (haven't set up pretty permalinks yet)

Can anyone shed any light on what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to forward all traffic to a sub-directory, use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^$ magento/    [L]
RewriteRule  (.*) magento/$1 [L]
```

Alternatively, you could setup a sub-domain or use a different port or some other criteria for `httpd.conf` to match to send all traffic straight to the desired directory.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure its not your site URL or wordpress URL in wordpress's settings?